Localization affecting the output of Powershell Get-Date command
I am trying to call Powershell Get-Date command within the batch script. Here is my batch script:
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myFormat=dd/MM
set locale_independent_get_date=powershell -NonInteractive -Command "Get-Date -Format %myFormat%"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i IN ('%locale_independent_get_date%') DO (
    set dd=%%i
    set mm=%%j
)
echo Day:[%dd%]
echo Month:[%mm%]

Because I explicitly specify the format with -Format switch, I was expecting to have the same output with every different locale settings.
But I see that, this is not true. Above Powershell command is not working as I expected with some different settings.
Isn't specifying the format explicitly with -Format enough to ensure locale independence? Clearly it is not, but I am wondering why.
Also, Instead of -Format, I tried -UFormat switch. In this case, command is working as expected in problematic cases too. Here what I did :
set myFormat=%%d/%%m
set locale_independent_get_date=powershell -NonInteractive -Command "Get-Date -UFormat %myFormat%"

But as we have many different possible settings, I cannot try all of them.
So, How can I be certain that this command is locale-independent?
Is there any documentation ? Or Do you know an easy way to test this code with all possible locale settings ?
Thank you !

In PowerShell the -Format string should be quoted, yours is not. Also, why bother using a forward slash in the string, then delimit it out anyhow? Also, don't enable delayed variable expansion, if you aren't needing it.

Example with singlequoting: For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\Sysem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -Command "Get-Date -Format 'dd MM'" 2^>NUL') Do Set "dd=%%G" & Set "MM=%%H". Alternatively with doublequoting: For /F "Tokens=1-2" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\Sysem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NonInteractive -Command "Get-Date -Format \"dd MM\"" 2^>NUL') Do Set "dd=%%G" & Set "MM=%%H".

@Compo, while quoting the -Format argument never hurts, it isn't necessary here: Get-Date -Format dd/MM works just fine (though not culture-invariantly). Fair point about not really needing a separator in this particular use case, but future readers may have use cases where the / is needed in the result string.

I'd assume that the space is not treated as a placeholder for some culture-appropriate date component. So using the examples I've provided above do solve the reported problem with the submitted code, (because the separator in the -Format string for the Get-Date PowerShell command, was never required at all by the OP).

@Compo, you're conflating two unrelated aspects, which is confusing: your claim that -Format (always) requires a quoted argument isn't true as such, as I've demonstrated. Using a space as the separator inside the argument indeed would require quoting. These considerations are solely related to PowerShell's parsing in argument-parsing mode, not to the specific issue at hand.

You're misrepresenting what I typed to suit your own purposes @mklement0. I said it should be quoted, not it must be quoted. I then used a space which is a default delimiter in a for /f loop, and showed it in use quoted, (which you admit is required). What I typed is correct, yet you feel compelled to imply otherwise.

@Compo:: It is incorrect to say that it should be quoted, for the reasons stated. Making that claim is a confusing distraction, so I felt compelled - and still do - to point that out. Nothing else was implied.

You should @mklement0! It is best practice to use consistent syntax so that you don't have to change behaviors, (when for instance the -Format string of Get-Date contains a space). Similarly, all of your set commands in your answer should be using doublequotes too, e.g., set "myFormat=dd\/MM". I am not incorrect, you simply do not understand the English meaning, and usage, of should. Should, is advisory, not compulsory; you use it for actions/responsibilities/duties that you think is best for the concerned subject. For this subject, it was best, as backed up by the code examples.

You should not, @Compo: The ability to specify words that do not contain metacharacters as barewords, i.e. unquoted, is an important feature in any shell. What makes your - in my estimation misguided - advice confusing is that you led with it, which can be misconstrued as implying that not following it is (part of) the problem at hand. In general, I suggest clearly framing incidental advice as such.

As I said, @mklement0, you are simply misconstruing an English term, with a clear meaning. I could understand protestations on a non English site, had I not directly followed up my comment with examples, to prove the points. (Comments, as you know are character limited, so my advice was split over two). 'Should' isn't interchangeable with 'must', and therfore no implication that it was a 'requirement' rather than advisory. In the case in point, had I not quoted it, (as you've agreed), my follow up code would not have worked. You answered the underlying question, I worked around the code issue.

@Compo, in casual speech, "should" and "must" are often interchangeable (e.g. when people point out typos in code, you may  see "x should be y"), so this ambiguity is best avoided, especially in the context of incidental advice that isn't clearly framed as such and has no bearing on the solution. That your solution, which changes the premise of the question, indeed requires quoting is beside the point (your alternative solution is helpful, but, for the reasons stated, I thought the question was worth addressing as asked, not least because the behavior is surprising).

@mklement0, this is absolutely incorrect, 'in casual speech, "should" and "must" are often interchangeable'. This is not casual chat it's a technical site. Teaching your boy that he should wash his hands after urinating, is good advice, which may prevent a future issue. However there's a huge difference between you 'should' wash your hands, and you 'must' wash them, (there are tens of thousands who don't, yet very few result in a issue.). As for my 'advice', it was not an answer, because I understood the underlying question, hence the reason it was posted as a comment, to fix the code issue.

@Compo, the semantic discussion is going nowhere, but let me leave no doubt that I think that "In PowerShell the -Format string should be quoted, yours is not." is misguided as general advice,
and, even if it were good advice, misleading in the case at hand, due to lack of framing.

That's fine @mklement, I have no issue with the fact that you, or anyone else, may misinterpret something I typed. But rest assured that the ensuing comments make it clear that I did not use the term 'should' to imply a compulsory action.


Escape the / char:
set myFormat=dd\/MM

Doing so ensures that .NET, which PowerShell is built on, uses the / literally in the output string, whereas unescaped use treats / as a placeholder, namely for the culture-appropriate date-component separator; e.g., with the de-DE (German) culture in effect, / turns into . in the output string.
The same applies analogously to the time-component separator, :
(As an alternative to \-escaping, you may use embedded '...' or "..." quoting, e.g. set myFormat=dd'/'MM, but to avoid quote character-escaping headaches when calling from outside PowerShell it is simpler to use the \ escape).
For more information, see the .NET docs:

List of special characters in format strings
Using the Escape Character (\)

Caveat:

While the above yields Arabic numerals (e.g. 11) and / for all cultures, as intended, the values of these numbers depend on the current culture's calendar - see the bottom section if you need to ensure that the result is always expressed as the components of a Gregorian date.


To provide a succinct demonstration in PowerShell code:
& {

  # Save the culture currently in effect.
  $prevCulture = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture

  # Loop over all given cultures.
  $args[0] | ForEach-Object {
    [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = $_

    # Contrast escaped and unescaped use.
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Culture = $_
      UnescapedSlash = Get-Date -Format dd/MM
      EscapedSlash = Get-Date -Format dd\/MM # Note the \
    }

  }

  # Restore the previous culture
  [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = $prevCulture

} 'en-US', 'de-DE'

The above prints:
Culture UnescapedSlash EscapedSlash
------- -------------- ------------
en-US   26/11          26/11
de-DE   26.11          26/11

Note how, for culture de-DE, the unescaped / in the format string turned into the culture-appropriate . separator, whereas the escaped form was retained verbatim.

Additionally ensuring use of the Gregorian calendar:
As noted, the month and day numbers are expressed in the current culture's calendar, as reflected in [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetType().Name.
Thus, with a culture that uses a calendar other than the Gregorian one in effect, the day and month number can differ (e.g., 26 November 2024 will yield '26/11' in cultures using the Gregorian Calendar, but '24/05' in ar-SA (Saudi Arabian Arabic, which uses the UmAlQuraCalendar calendar).
To ensure use of the Gregorian calendar, temporarily switch to the invariant culture, [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture, as part of the PowerShell CLI call:
@echo off
set myFormat=dd\/MM
set locale_independent_get_date=powershell -NonInteractive -Command "[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture=[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture; Get-Date -Format %myFormat%"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i IN ('%locale_independent_get_date%') DO (
    set dd=%%i
    set mm=%%j
)
echo Day:[%dd%]
echo Month:[%mm%]


@user3104363, the solution in this answer isn't locale-dependent (which was the point). Also, the use of standard formats such as the short date format doesn't come into play here. Please see my update, which demonstrates the effectiveness of the solution (paste into a PowerShell script). Do you get different results?

So, Powershell is using .Net under the hood ? If so, as you explain, I need to follow the rules you explain.
I am getting the same results when I try to execute the Powershell code.
But, when I try to modify my batch script as you explained :
set myFormat=dd/MM
set LOCALE_INDEPENDENT_GET_DATE_CMD=powershell -NonInteractive -Command "Get-Date -Format %DATE_FORMAT%"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i IN ('%LOCALE_INDEPENDENT_GET_DATE_CMD%') DO (
set dd=%%i
set mm=%%j
)
I am still getting unexpected output with Format: English (United States), Short Time: yyyy-MM-dd

Issue is solved. I was trying to test with more and more different settings. No issue found. Thanks a lot for helping me
Just to clarify, please confirm my understanding, the issue was originally related with using invalid delimiters. Using a valid delimiter fixed the issue. (I am currently ignoring different calendar types, only talking about Gregorian calendar.) @mklement0

Glad to hear it, @user3104363; my pleasure. No, the issue wasn't that the separator was invalid, it' s just that if / is unescaped, it acts as a placeholder rather than as a literal. That is, it then stands for whatever separator is customary in the current culture (see the de-DE example in the answer).
